# Not showing the "Body" content area when creating a new entry

Tags: error, publish-layout

I have just installed EE V3 and have created a channel called "homepage". I have gone to create a new entry fro this channel and it comes up with the "Title" and "URL Title" but not the text editor for the body content? See screenshot below:

[image]

I am not sure if i need to enable anything or install a add-on for this?

Look forward to hearing your thoughts.

Thanks
Jordan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, EE 3 has been out for only about a hot minute, but if I'm not mistaken, the core architecture of EE channels hasn't changed.

Have you created a **field group**, and added **fields** to it, and then assigned that **field group** to your channel? If not, EE will only use (be default) its two standard, required fields.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/channel/index.html

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/channel/fields/groups/form.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have now followed your steps and this is now working.

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome to the community. Would you mind marking my answer as correct?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome :) I have just marked it as correct for you now. Thank you again